# VB.NET Rest Client POST -d body

Tags: vb.net, api, rest, curl

I have a Rest API that i can query normal. Unfortunately I have to submit parameter values as body content.

CURL code is like

```
curl -X POST "https://URL" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: bearer [BEARER GOES HERE] -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"ids\": [\"ldt:b3b6ea07a6b848fdb5ca3e36bf1e3678:21475014799\",\"ldt:b3b6ea07a6b848fdb5ca3e36bf1e3678:8590616500\"]}"
```

I'm able to query the API like this:

```
Dim request = New RestRequest("/detects/queries/detects/v1, Method.POST)
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + bearer)
data_response = data_client.Execute(request)
data_response_raw = data_response.Content
```

The thing that I'm struggling with is to add the body / -d part of the curl request. The content is fairly simple:

```
{"ids":["ldt:b3b6ea07a6b848fdb5ca3e36bf1e3678:21475014799"]}
```

I tried **request.AddBody(Of RequestBody)(body)** but that gives me only a syntax error.

Can anybody give me a hint on this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you're using a 3rd party library with the RestRequest object. If so, could you specify what library you're using?

Comment: _request.AddJsonBody(body)_

Comment: @David using Imports RestSharp and Imports RestSharp.Authenticators

Comment: @Steve any hint on how to setup the body string best? I tried this 
Dim body As String = "{" + Chr(34) + "ids:[" + "ldt:b3b6ea07a6b848fdb5ca3e36bf1e3678:21475014799" + "]}" but that seems to fail

Comment: You pass an object not a json string. The method will convert the object to a json string. Start defining a class with just the ldt property, build a list of this class and then pass it to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have personally never used RestSharp, however here is the documentation related to specifying the request body of the RestRequest object: https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#request-body

Specifically, the documentation suggests using the AddJsonBody method: https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#addjsonbody

Here is an example using your desired body content:

```vb
Dim param = New With {Key .ids = {"ldt:b3b6ea07a6b848fdb5ca3e36bf1e3678:21475014799"}}
request.AddJsonBody(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

Davids hint did the trick - this is the code working

```
    Dim sb0 As New StringBuilder
    sb0.Append(Chr(123) + Chr(34) + "ids" + Chr(34) + Chr(58) + Chr(91))
    Dim append As String
    Dim zahl = 0
    Do Until zahl = nmbr2 - 1
        append = raw_d("resources")(zahl)
        sb0.Append(Chr(34) + append + Chr(34) + ",")
        zahl = zahl + 1
    Loop
    append = raw_d("resources")(zahl)
    sb0.Append(Chr(34) + append + Chr(34))
    sb0.Append(Chr(93) + Chr(125))
    Dim body As String = sb0.ToString

    Dim request = New RestRequest("xxx", Method.POST)
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + bearer)
    request.AddJsonBody(body)
    data_response = data_client.Execute(request)
    data_response_raw = data_response.Content
```

Maybe not the prettiest way to create the body but it works ;)